# SSRS 2008 - page break on muliple column report breaks to next column rather than next page

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a 2 column SQL Server Reporting Services report that displays a list of images in an album. In the column is a tablix which contains one Image and one Text Box grouped by album.

When I page break on my album group, it pushes the next group instance to the next column rather than next page. Is there any way to have it jump to the next page instead?

I followed instructions [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b281f56b-f0c5-4f77-afcd-718e1eaab987/how-to-force-a-page-break-on-a-multicolumn-report-?forum=sqlreportingservices) but it did not help: 
Here is an image of my rdl

[image]

Comment: Can you attach RDL and report screenshot?

Comment: the rdl has sensitive info, but i've added an image of it

Comment: Do you have column grouping?

Comment: @AnupAgrawal no column groups, just row groups grouping by albumID